# How to get data concurrency when put in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, strapi

I am making a form for candidates to submit recruitment information as shown below.... And the basic information is stored in the candidate information table and the CV file will be saved in the archive of Strapi CMS, Question The problem I am facing is that I want to get the file link after I push it to the repository and put it in the candidate dashboard

Comment: The question is unspecific. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It's unknown why is this a problem. If you need to get a link, get it.

Comment: You will have to consult the developers manual of Strapi or to ask their support team for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general pattern is that your backend should return an `id` or `url` after you post your entity. You would then use this returned `id` to get, update, or delete your entity.

The use of an asynchronous promise is typically used for the initial post, and when resolved with the `id`, you would update your client dashboard.